# Restore users in SVN after migration

Tags: svn, data-migration, svn-repository

How can I restore the user accounts after restoring the dump file, so that the repository starts functioning with the former user accounts and access rules?

Comment: I've the same problem. The project folders have anonymous access after the old repo dump has been loaded into the new repository.

I've followed almost all the steps from this post with the svnadmin create/dump/load commands. I only didn't do the svn co step which I think is not necessary on the server-side.

What should I do next to reclaim the old users and their access settings?

Comment: I forgot to add the link:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1882928/2256478

Answer (score 0):

According to [*Version Control with Subversion*](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate):

> The Subversion repository dump format describes versioned repository
>   changes only. It will not carry any information about uncommitted
>   transactions, user locks on filesystem paths, repository or server
>   configuration customizations (including hook scripts), and so on.

However, if you still have access to the old repository you may try copying the contents of `conf` subdirectory to the new repository (provided you are using vanilla svn authentication, and not HTTP/DAV).